# Cleaning event listener or any other attached resources when nodes are when is frequently updated

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, memory-leaks, dom-events

Guidelines on cleaning up event listeners and other resources attached to dynamic DOM nodes.

***Scenario***:

I am working on a legacy code that has an `add address` and an `edit address` button.

When user clicks on `edit` or `add` button an Ajax query `updateAddress` is made to get address form. It returns a HTML snippet to be placed in form section - which is

- either pre-populated address form to be edited (if edit button was clicked)
- or a blank address form to be filled in (if add button was clicked).

In `updateAddress` success callback, each field in form is then attached to a form validation events (e. on keyup/on blur etc).

When user clicks save address a request is called to save address. If save address is successful form section is removed, else user populated form continues to display on screen to show errors messages

***Question***:

How to manage the event listeners so that when user address is successfully saved, all the listeners have attached to form fields are cleared.

Comment: Maybe with this [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Yes, thanks @mootookoi.  I do understand in `saveAddress` sucess I can traverse though nodes to detach all listeners. But I am looking for some guidelines or best practices for such scenarios. Is there any way that the Javascript engine understands to remove the resources attached to nodes that have now been removed. from DOM, as in wrapper methods etc.?

Comment: @reactdesign If you already remove the form elements from the DOM, you don't need to detach event listeners from them. As soon as nothing references the objects any more, they will get garbage-collected.